# Why does shining a laser into an iPhone camera create these shapes?

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, camera

When I shine a laser light into an iPhone 6 camera I get these weird shapes:

[image]

The shapes are in no way in the background behind the laser. What causes these to appear? I know about typical lense flare, but something interesting seems to be happenning with the light to creat those circular shapes with fine rings inside.

Comment: I don't really understand why my question is downvoted? It seems to me like a good physics question involving light resulting in weird shapes when captured on camera.. Can someone explain why the downvote?

Comment: This site has an incredibly high bar for physics questions. Luckily, I'm into most questions asked with good intent.

Comment: @Zach466920 In my experience here, Ive had many high rep users respond with very elaborate answers to my question which was merely about whether or not a suit could hide heat signatures like the one in the Crysis game series. People seem to be very creative here about interesting little questions like this in my past experience on the site.

Comment: I look at the question page and note that only 20% of the questions have an up vote. I also notice that elaborate answers will be made, but then the writer never stops to up-vote the question itself.

Comment: @Zach466920 yes well I dont disagree.

Comment: My bet is those shapes are reflections off scratches in the lens. No practical way for anyone answering to test that, though.

Comment: @KyleOman the circular shapes seem to have fine rings sort of like a tree cross section. There must be some phenomena to explain how those curcular ring could occur.

Comment: Have you considered that the downvote came because you basically took some image and said, "Tell me what this is." without stopping to think that no one could possibly tell you what is going on with *your* device, except those that handle it directly or without you having shown that you had done anything to look for the answer yourself?

Comment: @KyleKanos Have you considered that I saw an interesting occurance in light patterns, had no idea what to call it, and came to the community who specializes in explaing such things to ask in the best way I knew how? I thought someone might say, "Oh cool, that's an interesting result from light, I can explain this"

Comment: Yes, I had considered that that is precisely what you did. I don't think this community is your personal identification service, and you shouldn't treat it this way.

Comment: Why do you care about downvotes if you have a 0.0 answer/question ratio?

Comment: The visible diffraction patterns remind me of the refraction patterns visible when viewing a bright light source through glasses covered with raindrops. This suggests that they are indeed due to motes of dust or scratches on the camera.

Comment: why the question is downvoted? I do not know, but I 've noticed a recurrent pattern: sometimes, even often, some (at random?), even with high punctuation I suspect, try to obfuscate the question with comments when there is no direct answer from a textbook. More often then not no one answer to the question 'why the downvote?'. Were is the conscience of the downvoters ? I do not know. Another reason to downvote that I can extensively document: The downvote is automatic in the impossibility to find in the literature an argument against an expressed non canonical answer.

Comment: The same as with your eyes, I think that the camera sensor can be damage by a laser. Take care. Nice question !

Comment: The frontiers of physics lay in the mystery of the unknown, not the comfort of lecture halls or textbooks. Why all the fear to take a risk, speculate and hypothesize.

Comment: @KyleKanos Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean you need to be hostile. It's obviously more interesting than most of the posts here. And the most fun part of physics is explaining physical phenomena, not teaching people how to math!

Comment: @Jahan: Find me hostility in my comments. It is clearly not "obviously more interesting than most" questions here, given that it's got a close vote, 2 downvotes & 3 guesses for answers. The only way to answer this question is to physically handle OP's phone, which makes for a poor question.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but those rings look to me like Haidinger fringes.  When monochromatic light falls on a thin, transparent plate or film, some of the light is transmitted and some gets reflected back, then reflected forward again, from the two surfaces.  The reflected light interferes with the transmitted light.  Whether the interference is constructive or destructive depends on how long the path of the reflected light is compared with the transmitted light, and so it's a function of viewing angle.  The result is concentric rings of alternating constructive and destructive interference.  In the case of this image, the surfaces doing the reflecting could be the front and back surfaces of the camera lens.

Answer (score 2):

I can identify the "rings of a tree" as a typical Airy function corresponding to a diffraction on an edge. In this case the edge is circular, as is the aperture of your camera.

You can best observe the same Airy-like "ringing" when you focus the laser and put some obstacle to the beam near the focus.

Multiple internal reflections in the lens can generate several different spots, like the light in a water droplet creates rainbows. But why they are *not* arranged in a single line? It is their azimuthal position that puzzles me the most.

Comment: The fringes are most probably *not* due to diffraction on the aperture. If the aperture would give so strong diffraction patterns, the images of the camera would be useless (recall: the point source diffraction pattern of the aperture is the point spread function of the objective!). They are most probably due to scratches or dust or other dirt on the objective (as suggested in one of the comments).

Answer (score 1):

I'll try my best to explain each part of the photo.

Everything that's red in the photo should be from the laser itself.

The nearly center white part of the photo comes from camera sensory overload. Lasers are extremely powerful concentrations of light, so when they directly hit the eye or an aperture they temporarily "blind" the source. In addition, because cameras tend to focus light to get an image, the effects of lasers can actually damage your camera. [Here's](http://www.laserist.org/camera-sensor-damage.htm) more information. It's the same reason the sun looks white if you look directly at it and then why you can't see for 30 seconds afterwords.

The yellow part of the picture, is that color because it's not at the center of the laser. There's not enough overload to make it white, but there's to much to register it as red.

Overall this picture is best described by "Lens-Flare". Here's a [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare) on that.

Comment: I get the lense flare part, but those circular shapes surrounding the light.. They seem to have grain, like rings of a tree.

Comment: @ColorQuestor I'd go with extremely strong lens flare. The Wikipedia article describes rings as something associated with lens flare.